# super-script & sub-script feature

Tags: feature-request

Why I still don't have **Super-script** or **Sub-script** formatting in Stack Exchange sites?

Is there any reason not to have it yet?

*Or it is there and I'm still not aware of it?*

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `<sup>` and `<sub>` HTML elements in your posts, as detailed in:

[What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

For example:

Some <sup>super</sup> and some <sub>sub</sub> scripts.